# Find function of degree n that goes through 2 points

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have 2 points, for example $P1(1;200)$ and $P2(100;10^9)$ <s>and a rational exponent</s> 
Now I want to find a function $f(x)$ goes through the two points <s>using the exponent n</s> and a "curvature factor n".

<s>If the exponent was 0, then the function should be equal to a linear function.</s>

Is there any procedure to find such a function?

<s>Edit: I am looking for a $x^n$ function.</s>

Example:
[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht5Sh.png)

Edit 2:
I've realized that my approach does not work the way i thought it would.
Simplified, my goal is to have a function that goes through 2 points and a "curvature" factor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using the exponent $n$"?  What does this mean?

Comment: If $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$ are on the curve $y=f(x)$ where $f(x)=ax^n$ then for a linear function $n=1$ (not $n=0$). For this situation though a single point gives enough information to find $a$. Would you clarify the question please.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, they mean "polynomial function of degree $n$", also known as "function of degree $n$" as in the question's title.

Comment: Is an answer of the form $a(x-b)^n$ acceptable?

Comment: The tag [exponential-function] should not be used on this question. Please consider editing your question and using other tags such as [polynomials] or [functions].

Comment: @StefanOctavian I would consider a polynomial function of degree $n$ to be represented by a polynomial all of whose terms are at most $n$, whereas the OP seems to be asking for a polynomial of pure degree $n$, i.e., homogeneous (although that is a silly term in this setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had eventually gotten the answer I was looking for and forgot to post it here:

Given 
$P1 = (X_1; Y_1)$ and 
$P2 = (X_2; Y_2)$ and 
curvature factor = $N$

then the formula I was looking for looked the following: 
$f(x) = \Large \frac{Y_2 - Y_1}{(X_2 - X_1)^N} \normalsize * (x - X_1)^N + Y_1$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you choose a functional form that has arbitrary constants in it and use the points to form equations to find those constants.  With two points we should have two constants.  A form you might use is $f_n(x)=a_n+b_nx^n$.  We plug in the points
$$200=a_n+b_n\cdot 1^n\\10^9=a_n+b_n\cdot100^n$$
These are two linear equations, so we can solve them for $a_n,b_n$.  Many functional forms will  not result in linear equations and you may need to find a solution numerically.

$$b_n=\frac {10^9-200}{100^n-1}\\a_n=200-b_n$$